# Remove Package using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, package

Using Windows 11 23H2 Build 22631.2861

Experimenting with Power Shell

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Getstarted -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage
```

This command is not removing the app Get Started

Tried a new fresh installation of windows using the media creation tool.
It does not show any output in the terminal either.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Getstarted -AllUsers` Gets the Get Started Application for all users. When you pipe it into Remove-AppxPackage you need to add the `-AllUsers` flag as well so that it removes from all users.

`Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Getstarted -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`

This command won't show output to the terminal. You can test that the package was removed by just running `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Getstarted -AllUsers`. If it doesn't have an output then the package was successfully removed. If the package is still installed, you will get this output:

```
PS C:\> Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Getstarted -AllUsers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

Name                   : Microsoft.Getstarted                                                                           
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US               
Architecture           : X64                                                                                            
ResourceId             :                                                                                                
Version                : 10.2312.1.0                                                                                    
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.Getstarted_10.2312.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe                                            
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Getstarted_10.2312.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe               
IsFramework            : False                                                                                          
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.Getstarted_8wekyb3d8bbwe                                                             
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe                                                                                  
PackageUserInformation : <User Information> 
IsResourcePackage      : False                                                                                          
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : False
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : Store
Status                 : Ok
```

Comment: That doesn't work. And to check if it has been removed no need a command line. You can just open the start menu where for me its pinned to the the top list and works fine.